# Writing chemical formulae on a curve with tikz and mhchem

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment, text, mhchem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=rectangle,rounded corners,draw] 
{\textcolor{blue}{\ce{R-C#N + H2O}}}; 
\node (Mid) at (0,0) [shape=circle,draw, fill=gray]
{\textcolor{green}{\Huge ?}};
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=rectangle,rounded corners,draw] {\textcolor{red}{\ce{R-C(OH)=NH}}};
\draw [>->>, ultra thick, cyan] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\pgftransformyshift{-.65cm}
\draw [decoration={text along path,
       text={On ice-grains: catalysed by hydronium ion}, text align={center}},decorate]  (-3,0) to [bend right=45]  (3,0);
\draw [>->>, ultra thick, dashed, magenta] (One) to  [bend left=45] (Two);
\pgftransformreset
\pgftransformyshift{.5cm}
\draw[decoration={text along path,
      text={Gas-phase},text align={center}},decorate] (-3,0) to [bend left=45]  (3,0);
\node (mental) at (0,1.75) {};
\node (non-mental) at (0,-1.75) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to replace "hydronium ion" by `\ce{H3O+}`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Adaptations

- to insert commands inside `text` option of `decoration` use curly brackets around it: `text={On ice-grains: catalysed by {\ce{H3O+}}`

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=rectangle,rounded corners,draw] 
{\textcolor{blue}{\ce{R-C#N + H2O}}}; 
\node (Mid) at (0,0) [shape=circle,draw, fill=gray]
{\textcolor{green}{\Huge ?}};
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=rectangle,rounded corners,draw] {\textcolor{red}{\ce{R-C(OH)=NH}}};
\draw [>->>, ultra thick, cyan] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\pgftransformyshift{-.65cm}
\draw [decoration={text along path,
       text={On ice-grains: catalysed by {\ce{H3O+}}}, text align={center}},decorate]  (-3,0) to [bend right=45]  (3,0);
\draw [>->>, ultra thick, dashed, magenta] (One) to  [bend left=45] (Two);
\pgftransformreset
\pgftransformyshift{.5cm}
\draw[decoration={text along path,
      text={Gas-phase},text align={center}},decorate] (-3,0) to [bend left=45]  (3,0);
\node (mental) at (0,1.75) {};
\node (non-mental) at (0,-1.75) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: I'm an idiot! Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSimmie Please not write that you are an idiot. Nobody is that.

Comment: I would put the tails in background :-)

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).